# Global Mass Matrix Assembly

Tags: finite-element-method

I am trying to assemble the global stiffness matrix from the local stiffness matrix using previous answer by @user21 [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/210983/global-stiffness-matrix-assembly/210992#210992).

I want to:
1- generate Hexahedron Element between 2 nodes only (I want to check the symbolic output with existing paper)
2- Generate the ith element symbolic mass matrix
3- conduct the FEA assembly procedure to get the global mass matrix.

My mass matrix for the element number 1.

[image]

I have simple beam with 2 nodes at each element. such as below:

[image: Beam Element Model]

each node has 2 DOF (this make it total 4 for element).
I want to generate HexahedronElement between nodes

The mesh setup

```
meshCoords = N[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}}];
incidents = {{1, 2}, {2, 3},{3, 4}};
```

I am not sure what user21 meant by single equation below:

```
(* single equation *)
dof = Length[meshCoords];
elementSize = Last[Dimensions[incidents]];
```

although my dof is 4.

Also I had some trouble understanding below input since it didn't generate 4x4 matrix for the element

```
(* symbolic elements for fun*)
elementValues = Array[#, {elementSize, elementSize}] & /@ {a, b};
Dimensions[elementValues]
{2, 3, 3}
```

once I have support to build above code, then I can run below assembly process.

```
matrixAssembly[ values_, pos_, dim_] := Block[{matrix, p},
  System`SetSystemOptions[ 
   "SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> 1}];
  matrix = SparseArray[ pos -> Flatten[ values], dim];
  System`SetSystemOptions[ 
   "SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> 0}];
  Return[ matrix]]
```

Comment: "I want to: 1- generate Hexahedron Element between 2 nodes only". Already that sentence does not make any sense. And what are `a` and `b` suppose to be? Please review your post and clarfify.

Comment: Well, maybe your problem is resolved by defining the mesh just like this: `meshCoords = N[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}];
incidents = {{1, 2}};`